# Tigger Melon growing a single female flower - any hope I can make it fruit?

Tags: greenhouse, pollination, melons, cross-pollination

I have a 12-14' (mostly vertical) [Tigger Melon](https://www.rareseeds.com/tigger-melon) vine growing that appears quite healthy. It has grown several male flowers in the past but currently it has it's first female flower and no visible male flowers.

Can I do anything to pollinate it or will it be lost? It's in an enclosed greenhouse space so manual pollination is typically expected.

I also have a healthy [Model Melon](https://www.rareseeds.com/store/vegetables/melons/model-melon) vine growing which *does* have male flowers (*but not female flowers)* - is cross-pollination possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They should be the same species (Cucumis melo); so, provided you do it properly and it takes, you should be able to cross-pollinate the Tigger melon flower with the Model melon pollen.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot! Also wondering if it's typical that there would be only a female flower without any male flowers? Is that maybe a sign something isn't quite right?

Comment: @Enigma It's not typical (usually a bunch of male flowers come first if there's a trend), but I wouldn't worry. It should eventually produce more flowers. Giving it some extra phosphorus might help. I like monopotassium phosphate and monoammonium phosphate.